# Phone number obligatory on new contact entry

Tags: google-api, google-contacts-api

I want to send a `POST` request on **Google Contacts API**. It works well at the moment.

But I wonder why I get a `400 Bad Request Error` if I don't specify a phone number.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <errors xmlns="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005">
  <error>
   <domain>GData</domain>
   <code>invalid</code>
   <internalReason>Phone number must not be empty</internalReason>
  </error>
 </errors>
```

If someone knows if I can bypass it ?

Notice that when you add a contact on [Google Contacts](http://contacts.google.com), there's not this restriction.

Comment: Do you have a copy of the raw request you're sending that you can share? Phone numbers should not be necessary, although if you have an empty phone number field, it would trigger that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that error because it's stated in the docs that these extension elements need to be provided a `rel attribute` or a `label attribute`:

> In the Contacts Data API, several elements are slightly more
>   restrictive than indicated in the documentation for the Contact kind.
>   In particular, a client must supply either a rel attribute or a label
>   attribute, but not both, for the following elements:
>
> gd:email gd:im gd:organization gd:phoneNumber gd:postalAddress

In short, you really need to provide the phone number.